# How to declare a mutable string in ruby 2.3 && ruby 3

Tags: ruby

I just pass into ruby 2.3 with the new frozen_string_literal option.

Over each of my file I add this line :

`# frozen_string_literal: true`

```
a = String('test')
a.frozen?        # true
a.gsub!('t', 'a') # raise error : OK
```

It work well but, is there a way to declare something like this :

```
a = MutableString('test')
a.frozen?        # false
a.gsub!('t', 'a') # aesa
```

Currently I make it work like this :

```
a = 'test'.dup
a.frozen?        # false
a.gsub!('t', 'a') # aesa
```

But it's a little bit ugly.

Comment: Did you mean `a.frozen? # false` in the last snippet?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. :)

Comment: Did you also mean that in the second snippet?

Comment: It's also possible to unfreeze a string with the Fiddle class,check out the 8th tip in http://www.blackbytes.info/2016/01/ruby-tricks/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elegant way to achieve this in future Ruby versions is [still being discussed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473). Until then, of course, the best bet would therefore be to avoid it, or to indeed use `String#dup` explicitly.

Technically, however, there's nothing to stop you from doing something like this:

```
def MutableString(x)
  x.dup
end

MutableString('...')
```